# How to add in yocto a bitbake layer only if machine name contains a specific substring?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a custom meta-layer with a bitbake recipe that add some files to the final image running do_install().

I want to execute this do_install (or the entire recipe) only if machine name contain a specific substring.

For example if I have 3 possibile machine names: "machine1", "machiABCne2", "machABine3", and the substring that I evaluating is "ABC", only if MACHINE="machiABCne2" I want include and run my custom recipe.

How can I do that in a general way, without creating multiple files and directories with all possibile machine names, but searching for the substring inside the machine name?

It's ok also running the content of do_install based on machine if not possibile in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below macro in your recipe(example.bb) file.

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE  =  "machiABCne2"
```

if the machine name is `"machiABCne2"` then only example.bb file will compile and  add to your rootfs otherwise bitbake throws error.
OR
you can also add this recipe for more machine
using below function in your `example.bb`

```
python () {
        machine = d.getVar("MACHINE", True)

        import re
        if re.match('imx6qpdlsolox',machine):
                subplatform = 'mx6qsabresd'
        elif re.match('imx6ul7d',machine):
                subplatform = 'mx6ulevk'
        elif re.match('imx6ull',machine):
                subplatform = 'mx6ullevk'
        elif re.match('imx',machine):
                subplatform = machine[1:]
        else:
                bb.fatal("optee-os-imx doesn't recognize this MACHINE")
        d.setVar("OPTEE_PLATFORM", subplatform)
}
```

hope the function will help you.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, because I'm talking about "if machine name contains a specific substring", not enumerating all possible machine names.

As you suggested I can add all possibile machine names, but I want to match machine name only if contains a specific substring

Comment: Is it possible to run this in do_install() {} ?, because I need to run the content of do_install based on machine

Comment: In particular I need to run bash commands into a do_install(). Is it possibile to mix your technique in a do_install with bash?

Comment: also  in other way you can try PACKAGES = "example-machine1 example-machine2 example-machine3"; FILES_machine1="files", FILES_machine2= "files", FILES_machine3="files'  and you need to use  in local.conf IMAGE_INSTALL_append="example-machine1" . here this will copy only machine1 files

Comment: yes my machine is defined correctly, but I'm searching a way to run your script as part of a do_install() {} with bash commands inside

Comment: YOU CAN CALL THAT PYTHON FUNCTION IN DO_INSTALL(0

Comment: How can I do that? I tried with "bb.build.exec_func("my_python_function", d)" but it didn't work, because I'm receiving error: "ShellParser._parse_shell(value='\n    bb.build.exec_func". Also, adding python in pront of do_install, I cannot run anymore shell scripts

Comment: Fix typo in previous comment: "Also, adding python in FRONT of do_install, I cannot run anymore shell scripts"